# Lines after subprocess.call is not executing

Tags: python

```
import time
import subprocess
import pyautogui
print subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\<program.exe'])
print "before sleep"

time.sleep(25)
print "its done"
```

Lines after subprocess.call is not executing  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` is blocking, your `print` will be executed once the subprocess you call finishes. You should use `subprocess.Popen` - it's non-blocking.